# Block content at the top of a hero-body with Bulma

Tags: html, css, bulma

I have a page with a fullheight hero element and I want to "stick" the content that is in `<div class="hero-body">` on the top of its container beacuse as now it centers automatically and I don't want that (it's a dashboard...).
How I can do?

Thanks in advance.

This is like what I want:
[image: the result I want]

This is currently my code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="hero is-fullheight-with-navbar">
    <!-- Hero head: will stick at the top -->
    <div class="hero-head">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns is-centered">
                <div class="column is-four-fifths">
                    <nav class="navbar is-spaced" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
                        <div class="navbar-brand">
                            <a class="navbar-item" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">
                                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/logo-m.png') }}" alt="logo">
                                <span class="has-text-grey-dark">&nbsp;by Artemis&trade;</span>
                            </a>
                            <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
                                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div id="navbarBasic" class="navbar-menu">
                            <div class="navbar-end">
                                <a class="navbar-item has-text-grey" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a>

                                <div class="navbar-item">
                                    <a class="button is-primary is-rounded" href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">
                                        <strong>Login</strong>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Hero content: will be in the middle -->
    <div class="hero-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns is-centered">
                <div class="column is-narrow">
                    <aside class="menu">
                        <p class="menu-label">Servizi Arc</p>
                        <ul class="menu-list">
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ url_for('dashboard.actions') }}" class="{{ 'is-active' if 'actions' in request.path else '' }}"><i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i>&nbsp;Actions&trade;</a>
                                <ul style="{{ 'display: block;' if 'actions' in request.path else 'display: none;' }}">
                                    <li><a>Members</a></li>
                                    <li><a>Plugins</a></li>
                                    <li><a>Add a member</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <a><i class="fas fa-shield-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Security&trade;&nbsp;<span class="tag is-primary is-rounded">In arrivo</span></a>
                        </ul>
                    </aside>
                </div>
                <div class="column is-7">
                    <div class="box">
                        <h1 class="title has-text-weight-light">
                            Hello, <span class="has-text-weight-bold">username</span>.
                        </h1>
                        <p class="subtitle is-5 has-text-grey">Seleziona un servizio per continuare...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Hero footer: will stick at the bottom -->
    <div class="hero-foot">
        <footer style="border-top: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 93%); padding-top: 1.7rem;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="columns is-vcentered is-centered has-text-centered-mobile">
                    <div class="column is-narrow">
                        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/logo-s.png') }}" alt="logo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="column is-3">
                        <h5 class="title is-5 has-text-grey-light has-text-weight-normal is-italic">
                            Arc ha come obiettivo il creare un'ecosistema semplice ma potente per aiutarti a gestire tutte le tue operazioni.
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column is-4 is-narrow">
                        &copy; 2020 <a href="https://rgbcraft.com" class="has-text-grey-darker">RGBCraft</a> & Artemis&trade;.
                        <br>
                        <i>Tutti i diritti riservati.</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column is-narrow">
                        Sitemap
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="has-text-grey" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a class="has-text-grey" href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following classes like below:

```
<div class="hero-body  is-align-items-stretch"> <!-- the important class is here -->
    <div class="container  is-flex">
      <div class="columns is-centered  is-flex-grow-1">
        <div class="column is-narrow">
            ....
        </div>
        <!-- the below one (is-align-self-center) is not mandatory if you don't want to center the banner -->
        <div class="column is-7 is-align-self-center">
           ....
        </div>
```

Full code

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="hero is-fullheight-with-navbar">
  <!-- Hero head: will stick at the top -->
  <div class="hero-head">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="columns is-centered">
        <div class="column is-four-fifths">
          <nav class="navbar is-spaced" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
              <a class="navbar-item" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/logo-m.png') }}" alt="logo">
                <span class="has-text-grey-dark">&nbsp;by Artemis&trade;</span>
              </a>
              <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </a>
            </div>

            <div id="navbarBasic" class="navbar-menu">
              <div class="navbar-end">
                <a class="navbar-item has-text-grey" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a>

                <div class="navbar-item">
                  <a class="button is-primary is-rounded" href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">
                    <strong>Login</strong>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Hero content: will be in the middle -->
  <div class="hero-body  is-align-items-stretch">
    <div class="container  is-flex">
      <div class="columns is-centered  is-flex-grow-1">
        <div class="column is-narrow">
          <aside class="menu">
            <p class="menu-label">Servizi Arc</p>
            <ul class="menu-list">
              <li>
                <a href="{{ url_for('dashboard.actions') }}" class="{{ 'is-active' if 'actions' in request.path else '' }}"><i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i>&nbsp;Actions&trade;</a>
                <ul style="{{ 'display: block;' if 'actions' in request.path else 'display: none;' }}">
                  <li><a>Members</a></li>
                  <li><a>Plugins</a></li>
                  <li><a>Add a member</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <a><i class="fas fa-shield-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Security&trade;&nbsp;<span class="tag is-primary is-rounded">In arrivo</span></a>
            </ul>
          </aside>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-7 is-align-self-center">
          <div class="box">
            <h1 class="title has-text-weight-light">
              Hello, <span class="has-text-weight-bold">username</span>.
            </h1>
            <p class="subtitle is-5 has-text-grey">Seleziona un servizio per continuare...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Hero footer: will stick at the bottom -->
  <div class="hero-foot">
    <footer style="border-top: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 93%); padding-top: 1.7rem;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="columns is-vcentered is-centered has-text-centered-mobile">
          <div class="column is-narrow">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/logo-s.png') }}" alt="logo">
          </div>
          <div class="column is-3">
            <h5 class="title is-5 has-text-grey-light has-text-weight-normal is-italic">
              Arc ha come obiettivo il creare un'ecosistema semplice ma potente per aiutarti a gestire tutte le tue operazioni.
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="column is-4 is-narrow">
            &copy; 2020 <a href="https://rgbcraft.com" class="has-text-grey-darker">RGBCraft</a> & Artemis&trade;.
            <br>
            <i>Tutti i diritti riservati.</i>
          </div>
          <div class="column is-narrow">
            Sitemap
            <ul>
              <li><a class="has-text-grey" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a></li>
              <li><a class="has-text-grey" href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are trying to achieve , pushing contents from bottom to top is  by  not displaying the top content
rather than setting the visibility of top portion to invisible

Try this out ,( in your class="hero-head")

```html
<div class="hero-head display is-hidden-mobile">
```

Please refer this  [documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/visibility-helpers/)  for more clarification

Comment: I edited the question and I added what I want to have.

Comment: this snippet works/appears just like your picture in desktop view

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work as intented.

Comment: why don't you try designing the webpage in bootstrap ? there is rich documentation  plenty of tutorials support